# express-validator retain input values

Tags: node.js, validation, express

Im new no NodeJS, ExpressJS and Jade. I'm using `express-validator` for validating a form.

In route:

```
req.assert('firstName', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.assert('lastName', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.assert('email', 'A valid email is required').isEmail();

var errors = req.validationErrors();
....
if (errors){
    res.render('users/new', {
      errors: errors
  });
} 
....
```

In `Jade`, to display error:

```
- if (errors)
div.alert.alert-error
    ul  
    - each error in errors
    li= error.msg
```

Above code works. I want the input values to be retain in the form so that user's don't to type it again.

```
input#name(type="text", name="name", value="?")
```

How?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can simply put back values to rendered view and interpolate it into input tag.

```
if (errors) {
  res.render('users/new', {
    errors: errors,
    firstName: firstName,
    ...
  });
}
```

and in jade template put

```
input#name(type="text", name="firstName", value="#{firstName}")
```

or

```
input#name(type="text", name="firstName", value= firstName)
```

it depends on your personal style.

It is better to define values like `person.first`, `person.last` and `person.email`, because you can put only `person` into your rendered view.

Answer (score 2):

Your `users/new.js` file

```
var body = req.body;
var form = {
    name: body.name,
    surname: body.surname,
    ...
};

req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('surname', 'Surname is required').notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
    //Pass both errors and form objects as local variables
    res.render('users/new', { errors: errors, form: form });
} else {
    ....//write to DataBase
}
```

new.handlebars file

```
{{#if errors}}
    {{#each errors}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{msg}}</div>
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
<form class="" method="post" action="/users/new">
     <p>Name*</p>
     <input type="text" value="{{form.name}}" name="name" />

     <p>Surname *</p>
     <input type="text" value="{{form.surname}}"name="surname" />
</form>
```